# AVFrame to QImage memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I am trying to decode the video frame to QImage and display it, but the below code which convert AVFrame to QImage cause memory leak. When I disable the below code the application works fine, but enabling cause to use more RAM and incenses by time.

```
    AVFrame *frameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
    int width = frame->width, height = frame->height;
    avpicture_alloc( ( AVPicture *) frameRGB, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, width,height);

    struct SwsContext *convert_ctx=NULL;
    enum PixelFormat src_pixfmt = (enum PixelFormat)frame->format;
    enum PixelFormat dst_pixfmt = PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    convert_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, src_pixfmt, width, height, dst_pixfmt,
    SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    sws_scale(convert_ctx,frame->data, frame->linesize,0,height, frameRGB->data, frameRGB->linesize);

    //decodedQimage = QImage( width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888 );
    for( int y = 0; y < height; ++y ){
       memcpy( decodedQimage.scanLine(y), frameRGB->data[0]+y * frameRGB->linesize[0],  frameRGB->linesize[0] );
    }

   av_free(frameRGB);
   sws_freeContext(convert_ctx);
```

Here `decodedQimage` is QImage type and int it like

```
        decodedQimage = QImage( outputwidth, outputheight, QImage::Format_RGB888 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`av_frame_free()`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ga979d73f3228814aee56aeca0636e37cc), not `av_free()`, to free `frameRGB`.